# Start application at start-up even without logging in

Tags: 18.04, remote-access, remote-login

I have a small server (with Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop) that I leave at my parent's house while I live abroad. I use ngrok since I cannot add a static IP to their router, and I set it up so that it starts whenever I turn the server on. It might happened that I have to remotely reboot it, so my question is the following: does ngrok (or any other application similarly configured) start even if I do not log in to the server? That is, does it start even if the machine is left at the login screen?

Comment: I know crontab @ reboot does, Not sure what ngrok is....Why do you need a static IP? Just forward the Port and use the Web facing IP + Port...or is this a security risk? Please advise if it is.

Comment: I am not familiar with ngrok. Can you make it a systemd service?